# How do I build the whole project, but then run a plugin goal in a single module?

Tags: java, maven

I have a web application project structured give or take like this:

```
foo
│   pom.xml
│
├───foo-backend
│       pom.xml
│
└───foo-web
        pom.xml
```

The module `foo-web` depends on `foo-backend`.

The parent POM contains the nested projects as modules:

```
...
<modules>
    <module>foo-backend</module>
    <module>foo-web</module>
</modules>
...
```

And the `foo-web` module enables the Tomcat plugin to correctly run this application without wrangling a separate app server installation:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

The problem I have is that if I run just this plugin for `foo-web`, the module `foo-backend` doesn't get rebuilt, and any old build output is used instead.

I set up IDEA to just build the project as part of the run configuration, but I'd like to keep as much of this not IDE-specific as possible, and as one cognitive step as possible.

Is there a way to tell Maven in a one-liner or configuration to:

1. `compile` the whole project; and then
2. `tomcat6:run` the `foo-web` submodule?

Comment: From your root directory, `mvn clean install && cd foo-web && mvn tomcat6:run` on command line does what you're looking for? And if the modules are not related, I would insist execution separated out. Or else you might want to draw out the tree on how these are related to each other.

Comment: You could skip the cd, I think with: mvn clean install && mvn -pl foo-web tomcat6:run

Comment: @nullpointer - I’m not a fan of multiple shell commands, because then the IDE doesn’t automatically take care of running the correct version of Java and Maven. (Which is required in this morass of legacy code that just stopped getting upgraded at random points in time depending on the project.) Also they are related, `foo-web` depends on `foo-backend`, this is why the problem occurs in the first place. (I’ll edit that in.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an execution of the `tomcat maven plugin` attached to one of the [maven phases](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). Since you want it to run after everything is compiler, it seems like the phase `process-classes` would be appropriate.

Also, I assume that you don't want to *always* run tomcat when trying to run maven phases, so it's better to make this execution *conditionally*.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>runTomcat</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <id>run-tomcat-on-compile</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>one</id>
              <phase>process-classes</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

To compile and run tomcat:

```
mvn process-classes -PrunTomcat
```